# How do I obtain the text inside a label which is inside a span using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

A block of code on a website I'd like to use Selenium ( with Python ) on ( for web scraping ) looks like the following -

```
<div class="exp_date">
  <span class="uppr_sec">
    <i class="exp_clndr"></i>
    <label> 04 Jan 2021 09:30 AM - 04 Jan 2021 10:30 AM </label>
  </span>
  
  <br>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
  
  <span class="lwr_sec">
    <i class></i>
    <label>Hosted By Some Random Person</label>
  </span>

</div>
```

I'd like to print the text enclosed in the `<label>` tags in both the spans i.e. "04 Jan 2021 09:30 AM - 04 Jan 2021 10:30 AM" and "Hosted By Some Random Person" in the Python console, using Selenium. However, I am not sure about the steps to do so, because the labels are nested in their respective spans, which are nested in a div.

Can someone please help me out with the code needed to do so ? (in Python)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any issues faced? Also is the usage of Selenium compulsory due to page being dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract and print the texts e.g. *04 Jan 2021 09:30 AM - 04 Jan 2021 10:30 AM* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.exp_date > span.uppr_sec label")])
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='exp_date']/span[@class='uppr_sec']//label")])
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.exp_date > span.uppr_sec label")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='exp_date']/span[@class='uppr_sec']//label")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: This is just everything I needed, thanks a ton! I've got another query though - I also have to identify a link starting with "abc.com" from the source HTML code of a given webpage, for which I'm planning to use `wd.page_source` (wd is the webdriver object ) to obtain the HTML source code of the page, and then, use Python RegEx to search for a string starting with "abc.com". Is there a Selenium - specific workaround to this, without using RegEx ( something like a search mechanism ) ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PranavN Sounds like a completely different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.